# marking a test as xfail with double parameterize in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, parametrized-testing

I have a pytest test that tests several inputs against two different databases.
i do it with using the parameterized mark twice:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "input_type",
    [
        pytest.param("input_1"),
        pytest.param("input_2"),
    ],
)
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "db_type",
    [
        pytest.param("db_type_1"),
        pytest.param("db_type_2"),
    ],
)
```

What I experience is only when running `input_1` with `db_type_2` (for example) the test fails due to a bug
but running the same input with different db passes.
I want to mark only the `input_1` and `db_type_2` combination as xfail while all other combinations should not be marked as xfail.
I cant find how to do so.

If marking `db_type_2` as xfail:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "db_type",
    [
        pytest.param("db_type_1"),
        pytest.param("db_type_2", marks=pytest.mark.xfail)
    ],
)
```

all inputs will be xfailed and it is not the behaviour I'm looking for.
Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: If you're still around, you can now accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can't mark the test based on the complete set of arguments in `pytest.mark.parametrize`/`pytest.param`, the information about other arguments is simply not there yet. Usually I move out the postprocessing of test parameters in a separate fixture which then can alter the test based on the complete set of test arguments. Example:

```python
@pytest.mark.parametrize('x', range(10))
@pytest.mark.parametrize('y', range(20))
def test_spam(x, y):
    assert False
```

We have 200 tests overall; suppose we want to `xfail` tests for `x=3`, `y=15` and `x=8`, `y=1`. We add a new fixture `xfail_selected_spams` that gets access to both `x` and `y` before `test_spam` starts and appends the `xfail` marker to test instance if necessary:

```python
@pytest.fixture
def xfail_selected_spams(request):
    x = request.getfixturevalue('x')
    y = request.getfixturevalue('y')

    allowed_failures = [
        (3, 15), (8, 1),
    ]
    if (x, y) in allowed_failures:
        request.node.add_marker(pytest.mark.xfail(reason='TODO'))
```

To register the fixture, use `pytest.mark.usefixtures`:

```python
@pytest.mark.parametrize('x', range(10))
@pytest.mark.parametrize('y', range(20))
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('xfail_selected_spams')
def test_spam(x, y):
    assert False
```

When running the tests now, we will get `198 failed, 2 xfailed` results since the two selected tests are expected to fail.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function that will be executed in tests collection time and handles the parametrization and the the `xfail` mark based on the data

```
def data_source():
    input_types = ['input_1', 'input_2']
    db_types = ['db_type_1', 'db_type_2']

    for tup in itertools.product(input_types, db_types):
        marks = []
        if tup == ('input_1', 'db_type_2'):
            marks.append(pytest.mark.xfail(reason=f'{tup}'))
        yield pytest.param(tup, marks=marks)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('test_data', data_source())
def test_example(self, test_data):
    assert test_data != ('input_1', 'db_type_2')
```

`itertools.product` allows to add another list of inputs without modifying any other part of the code except for the `if` condition for allowed inputs.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer.  I could only award a bounty once.  I slightly prefer the other answer, because it keeps the parameters and their values close to the test definition, moving only the expected failure combinations to an external function.